# how to automatically launch the application in wp7 without user actually clicking on the icon

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, launching-application

I am new to wp7
I want to create an application which should start automatically without user starting it.
Something similar to automatic virus scan on any PC.

Any suggestions please,A good example with code will make me understand better
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Not possible. And thanks to Microsoft for not making it possible.

Answer (score 4):

Applications must be started by the user. Depending on what you are attempting to build, a [`PeriodicTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.periodictask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) might be suitable. It allows you to run code for ~25 seconds every ~30 minutes.

However, the caveat is that this cannot occur after installation - the user must have run the application at least once. In additional, if the user does not re-run your main application (allowing you to re-create the task), it will stop being scheduled after 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

At most you can set a Reminder to popup at 12 PM every day to remind the user to open your app. You can even code to open your app when the user taps on the reminder. When your app is opened, set the reminder for next day.

If automatic opening of apps is allowed then all the thrash apps will be opening themseleves and make my life miserable. That's how viruses and trojans function. So if your app is legitimate then let the user decide to open it or not.