# how to write a background application,that can be run without any UI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to automatically launch the application in wp7 without user actually clicking on the icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411566/how-to-automatically-launch-the-application-in-wp7-without-user-actually-clicking)

how to write a background application (one that can be run without any UI)

any examples??
Thanks

Comment: lmgtfy: http://www.google.de/search?q=wp7+background+app yields http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/b8640e2f-6b57-4ced-87c1-115e9d8943e2/

Comment: I like how he just creates another question, when he's told it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create such applications for Windows Phone 7.

This was a deliberate design decision when the platform was created as such applications have a negative effect on battery life and device performance. They also break the desire of the platform to have transparency to the user about what the phone is doing. (i.e. it doesn't do anything the the user doesn't explicitly action themselves.)

An installed application (which has a UI component) can also use background agents (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942(v=vs.92).aspx) to perform some actions when the UI portion of the code is not running but there are a number of limitations on what they can do and how often they can run.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is possible, but requires so many hacks, that probably the OA will not get into this.
For anybody interested, please search the xda-developers forum, under wp7 hacking, and at the current point of time and knowledge - search under native development and preparing custom ROM images

and do not try to spam there, or the [FSM](http://www.venganza.org/) will eat your brain

BTW. have you tried redefining/solving you prroblem with http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Mango-Jump-Start-06-Windows-Phone-Multi-tasking--Background-Tasks ? // edit, ah, Matt has a better link for that